# Is it me or this Stotram makes you feel like you're travelling through different dimensions afterlife, and seeing your karma

Tags: vishnu

**Title**: Shree Vishnu Pratah - Smaranastotram

**Album**: Holy Chants On Vishnu And Mahalakshmi

**Artist**: G. Gayathri Devi, Saindhavi, Priya, R. Shruti

***This stotram really makes you feel like, you're travelling through the road of different afterlife, and there are darkness everywhere and you're trying to reach to the end where Narayan is waiting for you, but it's very difficult.***

Comment: Hi, welcome to HSE. This is opinion-based, and thus off-topic, but you could share it in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) if you want other people's thoughts.